# The difference between "ans Glas klopfen" and "gegen ein Glas klopfen"

Tags: difference, preposition

I'm watching a movie and in one of the scenes a person wants to attract public attention and taps against a glass.

The subtitles say "Jemand klopft **gegen** ein Glas.". But in DWDS it's "**an** das Glas klopfen".

What is the difference between "**gegen** ein Glas klopfen" and "**an** ein Glas klopfen"? Which one is correct in this situation?

Comment: I believe "klopfen an" is the correct option but there is no real difference in meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

»ans Glas klopfen« and »gegen ein Glas klopfen« can describe two different things.

The second one, which you encountered in the movie, is correct here, because in Germany people typically tap their spoon against a glass at larger gatherings to attract attention, e.g. if they want to give a short speech or if they want the wedding couple to kiss (in this case the other guests will join into the glass-tapping).

»ans Glas klopfen« can mean, more generally, to knock on (anything made from) glass, e.g. the glass of a door or window to attract the attention of somebody inside the house.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer!

Comment: Thanks, but users are asked to wait 24 h for other answers that may be better before accepting.

Answer (score 1):

*Gegen* in general means a direction (like *towards*), while *an* strongly indicates a contact/touch.

An example for this general meaning is:

> Die Fenster gehen gegen Osten

In your special case there would be no knocking noise in case you stopped earlier, so it is pretty clear, that *gegen* here also includes contact (like *against*).

This is confirmed by [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/gegen), meaning I/1/d, where it is stated:

> bezeichnet die Berührung, den Endpunkt einer zielgerichteten Bewegung, Handlung

So as already stated *an* is more common and shorter too.